# Jekyll custom hook in `_plugins` folder is not executed

Tags: jekyll

Before we start, I do know custom hooks are not executed by Github pages, I'm suffering this issue locally(`bundle exec jekyll serve`).

I manage my own [Github pages](https://github.com/LazyRen/LazyRen.github.io), and I found a great [post](https://blog.4dcu.be/programming/2020/03/13/Jekyll-Blog.html) about Jekyll hook that I wanted to try it out by myself.

I followed the instruction, first created `_plugins` folder at the root of my repo,
and created my own `*.rb` file.

But my hook is not executed at all!

I even downloaded the source file of the [example blog](https://github.com/4dcu-be/4dcu.be), but I couldn't notice any difference that might cause this issue.
FYI, local serve of the example blog worked well with all the hooks executed.

If you can help me on this issue, it would be very much appreciated. Here is [the WiP commit](https://github.com/LazyRen/LazyRen.github.io/commit/c94dc1bdb7ea71fa1f3d4d83a6f0484d9ef670d2) of my blog.

Thank you.